# Grid of two xaml columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I try to show 2 xaml pages next to each other in a grid with one row and 2 columns. I tried this:

```
<Window x:Class="HostApplicationWindows.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HostApplicationWindows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <local:PluginSelection x:Name="LeftPage" Grid.Column="0" />
        <local:PluginViewBig x:Name="RightPage" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But that gives me an "XamlParseException" (Page can have only Window or Frame as parent.)

What does that mean?

Comment: You got an error about a Page and you didn't show us anything with pages.

Comment: The parent of your `Page` is a `Grid`. As the error says, you can only have a `Window` or `Frame` be the parent. Do they need to be a `Page`? Make them a `UserControl` instead and you should be fine.

Comment: @WasGoodDone Thanks!